# How can I provide a security for users access the files in Samba?

Tags: samba, security, file-sharing

I'm creating a Samba file Server and each user with 5gb space, how can I provide a security for users access the files? like authentication and credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Winbind . It's really easy.

You can add a user with basic authentication,username and password.

You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba winbind
```

For its configuration and use read this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-file-sharing-with-samba/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.